# I m not able to insert events into the Google calendar API ?

Tags: google-app-engine, calendar, google-calendar-api

as I m new for the Calendar API so i came up with the authorization part but not able to insert events into the calendar.
While inserting events it is showing the the error

```
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
```

Here is my entire code, if it will help:

```
package com.drive;

import java.io.IOException;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
//import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.util.ArrayMap;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.client.util.GenericData;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.*;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.CalendarList;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Events;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Acl;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.AclRule;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.CalendarListEntry;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventAttendee;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

/**
 * Entry sevlet for the Plus App Engine Sample. Demonstrates how to make an authenticated API call
 * using OAuth2 helper classes.
 *
 * @author Nick Miceli
 */
public class DriveSampleServlet extends AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet {


  // List the scopes your app requires. These must match the scopes
  // registered in the Admin console for your Google Apps domain.
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)  throws IOException, ServletException {

        User user =UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser();

       if(user!=null){

         AuthorizationCodeFlow authFlow = initializeFlow();
         Credential credential = authFlow.loadCredential(getUserId(req));

         Calendar calendar =new Calendar.Builder(Utils.HTTP_TRANSPORT,Utils.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("ashishwaiting96").build(); 
        // Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(Utils.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Utils.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("ashishwaiting96").build();

      /*  resp.getWriter().print("success"+calendar.acl().list(" sial.com_li54bsfij3i31a9a8uqdvurr3c@group.calendar.google.com").execute());
    */

         com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar calendar1 = calendar.calendars().get("primary").execute();

         resp.getWriter().print("success"+calendar1.getSummary()+"  "+calendar1.getKind()+"  "+calendar1.getDescription());


         Event event = new Event();

         event.setSummary("appointment");
         Date startDate = new Date();
         Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
         DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
         event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
         DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
         event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));

         Event createdEvent = calendar.events().insert("primary", event).execute();

         System.out.println(createdEvent.getId());





       }    
}
  @Override
  protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws ServletException, IOException {
    return Utils.initializeFlow();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    return Utils.getRedirectUri(req);
  }

}
```

snippet 2:

```
package com.drive;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.datastore.AppEngineDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

class Utils {

  private static final AppEngineDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY =
      AppEngineDataStoreFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  private static GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = null;

//  private static  Set<String> SCOPES = Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.PLUS_ME);

  private static  List<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<String>();
  static final String MAIN_SERVLET_PATH = "/DriveSampleServlet";
  static final String AUTH_CALLBACK_SERVLET_PATH = "/oauth2callback";
  static final UrlFetchTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new UrlFetchTransport();
  static final JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  private static GoogleClientSecrets getClientSecrets() throws IOException {
    if (clientSecrets == null) {
      clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
          new InputStreamReader(Utils.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json")));
      Preconditions.checkArgument(!clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
          && !clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter "),
          "Download client_secrets.json file from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plus "
          + "into plus-appengine-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
    }
    return clientSecrets;
  }

  static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {
      //SCOPES.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
      SCOPES.add(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
//    SCOPES.add(PlusDomainsScopes.PLUS_ME);
//    SCOPES.add(PlusDomainsScopes.PLUS_PROFILES_READ);
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow gf= 
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(     
           HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getClientSecrets(), SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(
           DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();

    return gf;
  }


  static String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) {
    GenericUrl requestUrl = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
    requestUrl.setRawPath(AUTH_CALLBACK_SERVLET_PATH);
    return requestUrl.build();
  }

}
```

I added the secret.json file which is working,
any help..

Comment: Can you do any operations on the calendar?

Comment: I m able to do only the authorization part,but If i m trying to insert any event then it is showing an error.I think m not able to access token like something not sure

Comment: Did you enable access through the console?

Comment: yes I did everything..like enable Calendar API then created a client Secret Id(keeping JSON format) ,created a consent screen too.made calendar public

Comment: What about the parts of your code that get the calendar or the acls. Do those parts work?

Comment: no Eric those lines also don't work,they show the same insufficient permission error,

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient Permission error is thrown when the authenticated user does not have sufficient permissions to execute this request. When I looked at the code, I see the line

//  private static  Set SCOPES = Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.PLUS_ME);

is commented out. When you are trying to add the calendar events, there should be scopes with WRITE authorization to the users profile in the code. You can try uncommenting the above line or uncomment the below lines:

//    SCOPES.add(PlusDomainsScopes.PLUS_ME);
//    SCOPES.add(PlusDomainsScopes.PLUS_PROFILES_READ);

Here are the links that will help you:

[link1](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/plus-appengine-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/plus/PlusSampleServlet.java?spec=svn.samples.b50d3af744d06f87916dd52a514108ccdeabcaf7&repo=samples&r=b50d3af744d06f87916dd52a514108ccdeabcaf7)

[link2](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/cmdline/CalendarSample.java?repo=samples)

Also, if you are trying to add event into some one's calendar then you should have permission to do that. Please check this scenario too.

Comment: while I m uncommenting the scopes it is showing an error on PlusDomainsScopes , for that it is telling me to create a class for that,also I m storing events into my calendar itself which i made public

Comment: In second link this is the whole code for that or i just need to make changes,but thank you anyway :)

Comment: i commented out those line ,but not able to do that